# TensorFlow cannot feed value error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, logistic-regression

I am implementing a logistic regression function. It is quite simple and work properly up until I get to the part where I want to calculate its accuracy. Here is my logistic regression...

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# tf Graph Input
x = tf.get_variable("input_image", shape=[100,784], dtype=tf.float32)
x_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[100, 784])
assign_x_op = x.assign(x_placeholder).op

y = tf.placeholder(shape=[100,10], name='input_label', dtype=tf.float32)  # 0-9 digits recognition => 10 classes


# set model weights
W = tf.get_variable("weights", shape=[784, 10], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
b = tf.get_variable("biases", shape=[1, 10], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

# construct model
logits = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)  # Softmax

# minimize error using cross entropy
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=1))

# Gradient Descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

saver = tf.train.Saver()

# launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    # training cycle
    for epoch in range(FLAGS.training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/FLAGS.batch_size)
        # loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
            # Assign the contents of `batch_xs` to variable `x`.
            sess.run(assign_x_op, feed_dict={x_placeholder: batch_xs})
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={y: batch_ys})

            # compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch + 1) % FLAGS.display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))

    save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
    print("Optimization Finished!")
```

As you can see it is a basic logistic regression and function and it works perfectly.

It is important to not that `batch_size` is `100`.

Now, after the code snipped above, I try the following...

```
# list of booleans to determine the correct predictions
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
print(correct_prediction.eval({x_placeholder:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))

# calculate total accuracy
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

However the code fails on `correct_prediction`. I get the following error...

> % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
>   ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10000, 784) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(100, 784)'

I believe I get this error because of the value I am trying to assign the placeholder for `x`. How can I fix this? Do I need to `reshape` the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
x_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[100, 784])

y = tf.placeholder(shape=[100,10], name='input_label', dtype=tf.float32)  # 0-9
```

avoid fixing the first dimension as 100, since it prohibits you from using any other batch size (so if the number of images in `mnist.test.images` is different from 100, you'll get an error). Instead specify them as `None`:

```
x_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])

y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,10], name='input_label', dtype=tf.float32)  #
```

Then you can use any batch size

Comment: I see. Is there any other workaround? I am restoring my model elsewhere and the way I setup my variables is kind of important.

Comment: If you want to keep the first dimension as 100, you'll have to feed it with batch size 100. So one option might be to partition mnist.test.images (and mnist.test.labels) to chunks of 100, calculate the accuracy on each one of them, and then average over the accuracies.